# Using json as a variable but getting null error

Tags: linux, bash, json, jq

I am trying to use json as a variable in a bash script.

```
JSON=$(
  jq -n -c --arg 1a "$PRIMARYPVTIP1" --arg 1b "$PRIMARYPVTIPOCID1" --arg 2a "$PRIMARYPVTIP2" --arg 2b "$PRIMARYPVTIPOCID2" --arg 3a "$PRIMARYPVTIP3" --arg 3b "$PRIMARYPVTIPOCID3" --arg 4a "$PRIMARYPVTIP4" --arg 4b "$PRIMARYPVTIPOCID4" --arg 5a "$PRIMARYPVTIP5" --arg 5b "$PRIMARYPVTIPOCID5"'[{
    ipAddress: $1a,
    isBackup: false,
    isDrain: false,
    isOffline: false,
    name: ($1b + ":11011"),
    port: 11011,
    targetId: $1b,
    weight: 1
  },
  {
    ipAddress: $2a,
    isBackup: false,
    isDrain: false,
    isOffline: false,
    name: ($2b + ":11011"),
    port: 11011,
    targetId: $2b,
    weight: 1
  },
  {
    ipAddress: $3a,
    isBackup: false,
    isDrain: false,
    isOffline: false,
    name: ($3b + ":11011"),
    port: 11011,
    targetId: $3b,
    weight: 1
  },
  {
    ipAddress: $4a,
    isBackup: false,
    isDrain: false,
    isOffline: false,
    name: ($4b + ":11011"),
    port: 11011,
    targetId: $4b,
    weight: 1
  },
  {
    ipAddress: $5a,
    isBackup: false,
    isDrain: false,
    isOffline: false,
    name: ($5b + ":11011"),
    port: 11011,
    targetId: $5b,
    weight: 1
  }]'
)

/bin/oci --profile $USER nlb backend-set update \
--backend-set-name $BACKENDSETNAME \
--network-load-balancer-id $NLBOCID \
--backends "$JSON" \
--force
```

I am getting a error as

```
++ jq -n -c --arg 1a 100.100.100.101 --arg 1b ocid1.privateip.oc1.ap-mumbai-1.abrg6ljrf6ink5hr5huugsjp4ibe5tfmszo76okxkhytnxxl4fxzfabhg7gq --arg 2a 100.100.100.102 --arg 2b ocid1.privateip.oc1.ap-mumbai-1.abrg6ljr4jz3os5x66p4u6xuzys2etcauw4e7ncp4tjm5h2l2in7gotth6hq --arg 3a 100.100.100.103 --arg 3b ocid1.privateip.oc1.ap-mumbai-1.abrg6ljrcvy4dcpag3ru4iu6qpswpaixayeowbh5l2tbajzd6q3ifwdax45q --arg 4a 100.100.100.104 --arg 4b ocid1.privateip.oc1.ap-mumbai-1.abrg6ljrmcto6xtjxstccijpwxucixgvg4pxmk6zghjrqgckhhizjfdvp2gq --arg 5a 100.100.100.105 --arg 5b 'ocid1.privateip.oc1.ap-mumbai-1.abrg6ljrldpkuo2byuar7vh6vofmtxejrstgi24n6dpixhsvvmjos2huhn6q[{
    ipAddress: $1a,
    isBackup: false,
    isDrain: false,
    isOffline: false,
    name: ($1b + ":11011"),
    port: 11011,
    targetId: $1b,
    weight: 1
  },
  {
    ipAddress: $2a,
    isBackup: false,
    isDrain: false,
    isOffline: false,
    name: ($2b + ":11011"),
    port: 11011,
    targetId: $2b,
    weight: 1
  },
  {
    ipAddress: $3a,
    isBackup: false,
    isDrain: false,
    isOffline: false,
    name: ($3b + ":11011"),
    port: 11011,
    targetId: $3b,
    weight: 1
  },
  {
    ipAddress: $4a,
    isBackup: false,
    isDrain: false,
    isOffline: false,
    name: ($4b + ":11011"),
    port: 11011,
    targetId: $4b,
    weight: 1
  },
  {
    ipAddress: $5a,
    isBackup: false,
    isDrain: false,
    isOffline: false,
    name: ($5b + ":11011"),
    port: 11011,
    targetId: $5b,
    weight: 1
  }]'
+ JSON=null
+ /bin/oci --profile SERDY nlb backend-set update --backend-set-name boom --network-load-balancer-id ocid1.networkloadbalancer.oc1.ap-mumbai-1.amaaaaaakfvuezya7tkgva6g3d5qjl6fsr3oy64k4xhcwxzcvxyoie4v6mlq --backends null --force
```

You can see it is showing **JSON=null**

Can someone please help me T.I.A

Comment: I rolled back your recent edit as it deleted all details that were necessary to answer the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two very different errors in your code.  Fortunately, both are simple to fix.

1. There is a typo in the command line, a missing space before the actual `jq` expression string:

   ```
   ... --arg 5b "$PRIMARYPVTIPOCID5"'[{
   ```

   should be

   ```
   ... --arg 5b "$PRIMARYPVTIPOCID5" '[{
   ```
2. Internal `jq` variables can not have names starting with digits.  This means that all your `$1a` etc. variables are invalid.  Swapping the digit and the letter (`$1a`-->`$a1` etc.) makes these variable names valid.

- Ideally, you should also quote *all* variables in the final call to `oci`, not just the variable holding the JSON document.

---

Bonus: Slightly more compact JSON construction:

```bash
args=(
        100.100.100.101 ocid1.privateip.oc1.ap-mumbai-1.abrg6ljrf6ink5hr5huugsjp4ibe5tfmszo76okxkhytnxxl4fxzfabhg7gq
        100.100.100.102 ocid1.privateip.oc1.ap-mumbai-1.abrg6ljr4jz3os5x66p4u6xuzys2etcauw4e7ncp4tjm5h2l2in7gotth6hq
        100.100.100.103 ocid1.privateip.oc1.ap-mumbai-1.abrg6ljrcvy4dcpag3ru4iu6qpswpaixayeowbh5l2tbajzd6q3ifwdax45q
        100.100.100.104 ocid1.privateip.oc1.ap-mumbai-1.abrg6ljrmcto6xtjxstccijpwxucixgvg4pxmk6zghjrqgckhhizjfdvp2gq
        100.100.100.105 ocid1.privateip.oc1.ap-mumbai-1.abrg6ljrldpkuob2yuar7vh6vofmtxejrstgi24n6dpixhsvvmjos2huhn6q
)

JSON=$(
jq -n '
        [
            range(0;$ARGS.positional|length;2) |
            { ipAddress: $ARGS.positional[.], targetId: $ARGS.positional[.+1] }
        ] |
        map( . += { isBackup: false, isDrain: false, isOffline: false, weight: 1, port: 11011 } ) |
        map( . += { name: ([.targetId, .port] | join(":")) })' --args "${args[@]}"
)
```

Here, the first `[ range() | { ... } ]` returns an array of objects that only has the correct `ipAddress` and `targetId` keys and corresponding values.  These objects are then expanded upon with two `map()` calls.  The first `map()` adds the static data to each element while the second `map()` adds the `name` key whose value depends on both the `targetId` and `port` keys having previously been set.